# How to install libsystemd-journal-dev on Wily (JHBuild issue)

Tags: gnome, dependencies, systemd, jhbuild

I'm trying to build gnome apps using [JHBuild](https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/getting-started.html.en). But this is what I get

```
$ jhbuild build gnome-music
Required packages:
  System installed packages which are too old:
    (none)
  No matching system package installed:
    libsystemd-journal (libsystemd-journal.pc, required=201)
    libtiff 
jhbuild build: Required system dependencies not installed. Install using the command 'jhbuild sysdeps --install' or to ignore system dependencies use command-line option --nodeps
```

And when I run `$ jhbuild sysdeps --install`, I get,

```
Required packages:
  System installed packages which are too old:
    (none)
  No matching system package installed:
    libsystemd-journal (libsystemd-journal.pc, required=201)
    libtiff 
Optional packages: (JHBuild will build the missing packages)
  System installed packages which are too old:
    WebKit (webkit2gtk-4.0.pc, required=2.11.90, installed=2.8.5)
  No matching system package installed:
I: Installing dependencies on system: libsystemd-journal libtiff
I: Using apt-file to search for providers; this may be slow.  Please wait.
I: No native package found for libsystemd-journal (/libsystemd-journal.pc)
I: No native package found for libtiff (/usr/include/tiff.h)
I: Nothing to install
```

I searched for the file [libsystemd-journal.pc](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=libsystemd-journal.pc&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) and found that it's in the package `libsystemd-journal-dev`. But there is no such package available for Wily. So what can I do..?

Comment: Try this: [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/libsystemd-journal-dev/219-7ubuntu3](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/libsystemd-journal-dev/219-7ubuntu3) libsystemd-journal-dev 219-7ubuntu3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download and install this compatibility package which provides the necessary libsystemd-journal.pc file.

Just download and install a .deb from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/wily/amd64/libsystemd-journal-dev)
 .
Then re-run `$ jhbuild sysdeps --install` and the error would go away.

Answer (score 0):

Try `jhbuild build --nodeps gnome-music`

Or try building in debian Testing or Fedora 23 which are known to be better supported.